# Relative dualizing sheaf of the family $\varphi: C\rightarrow \mathbb{A}^1$ where $C$ is the vanishing locus of $xy=t^k$ in $\mathbb{A}^3$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, sheaf-theory, algebraic-curves

This is an exercise from the book *Moduli of Curves*.

Let $C$ be the vanishing locus of $xy= t^k$ in $\mathbb{A}^3$. Define a morphism
$$\varphi:C\rightarrow \mathbb{A}^1, (x,y,t)\mapsto t.$$
Then $C$ is a family of curves over $\mathbb{A}^1$. Show that the relative cotangent bundle of $\varphi$ on $C^* = C\backslash \{(0,0,0)\}$ extends to $C$, and that the sections on $\varphi^{-1}(0)$ satisfy the residue condition.

I learned how to resolve a node in the case of a curve. But here any neighborhood of the point (0,0,0) is a surface. Could someone give me a hint? Or a detailed solution is much more appreciated :)

Comment: About the first part. The scheme $C$ is integral and regularly immersed in ${\bf A}^3$ by construction. Also, the map $\phi$ is generically smooth. So there is an exact sequence $$N_{C/{\bf A}^3}\to\Omega_{\pi_3}|_C\to \Omega_\phi\to 0$$ (where $N$ is the conormal bundle and $\pi_3$ projects on the 3rd factor) which is actually also exact on the left because the two involved sheaves are locally free, $C$ is integral and the sequence is generically exact on the left. So you may defined the extension of $\Omega_\phi|_{C^*}$ by the formula ${\rm det}(\Omega_{\pi_3})|_C\otimes N^\vee.$